# How to Calculate IRR in SSRS reports dynamically

Tags: reporting-services, irr

Can you please let me know that how we can write code for irr calculation in SSRS Reports.
IRR basically requires two parameters i.e. Payments array and guess value.
But i don't know how to build array dynamically in SSRS reports.

Comment: Ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the custom code for that, please refer to following link that definitely help to get it done

[How to use the IRR function](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/871bf648-caf7-45b0-a49b-a5ecee3aed65/how-to-use-the-irr-function)